# When pinning to web shortcuts to a windows 10 tile, the icon changes

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, start-menu, live-tiles

I have created windows shortcuts to web sites I often visit, I have then manually set the icon of the shortcut to the logo of the website

[image]

These are web shortcuts where the shortcut target looks like this (using chrome as the browser)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.youtube.com --kiosk

When I add these shortcuts to programs

1) run -> shell:programs

2) paste copy of shortcut into folder

They appear in the list of programs in the start bar with the correct icon and look great

[image]

But when I pin these to the start menu as a tile, it doesn't respect the icon and instead uses the chrome icon

[image]

How can I fix this?  Why does it not use the assigned icon of the shortcut?